# Limit screen programmatically for screen shot

Tags: ios, image, screenshot

I am making application related to images.
I have multiple images on my screen.
I had take screen shot of that.
But I want to take screen shot of some limited area,
so basically I want to limit the frame for screen shot.
Below is my code for screen shot.

```
-(UIImage *) screenshot
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.bounds.size, YES, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);

    [self.view drawViewHierarchyInRect:self.view.frame afterScreenUpdates:YES];

    image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return image;
}
```

after take screen shot I am using it by below code in facebook share method,

```
UIImage *image12 = [self screenshot];

[mySLComposerSheet addImage:image12];
```

Comment: So what exactly you need here...

Comment: want to provide  Custom frame to snapshot

Comment: And upper code doesnt provide me whole image of the screen.

Comment: BY using this code, in a screenshot image little top most And little Bottom part are not seen in image, That`s I want to salve out.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
-(UIImage *)ConvertToImage:(UIView *)view
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(view.frame.size);
    [view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return viewImage;
}
```

Comment: Can i provide rect frame to it?

Comment: I think U can user view as frame, try making it transparent and position it over the image (or part of an image) u like to snapshot, and call this method... Think it will work

Comment: Actually your code work nicely, But it`s not give me a perfect snapshot of my view, some part of my corner is not seen while snapshot.

Comment: I dont know if U done it correcty cause I use this code and it works fine for me

Comment: I am doing it for iphone ratina 4 inch, i hope it`s not cause any problem.  And I had change one line of your code             [self.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()]; to [self.view drawViewHierarchyInRect:self.view.frame afterScreenUpdates:YES];

Comment: I had did it due to using layer i got error as below:property "layer" not found on object of type viewcontroller2

Comment: #import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

Comment: Yup I did. But after put self.view .layer everything are salved. By the way thanx man.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly you want to take a screenshot and crop it. There are a lot of alternatives, this is one of them:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
[self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext(); /* this is the full capture */
CGRect r = (CGRect){{image.size.width * 0.25, image.size.height * 0.25}, {image.size.width / 2, image.size.height / 2}};
CGImageRef ref = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(image.CGImage, r);
UIImage *cropped = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:ref]; /* this is the center area */
CGImageRelease(ref);
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Just capture the right view and calculate the right rectangle.

In iOS 7 you can use the `UIView`'s faster `drawViewHierarchyInRect:afterScreenUpdates:` instead of `renderInContext`.

Comment: My problem is , I am using code that I have written in this que, By using that the screen shot image doesn`t show my whole screen,  Little part of the Top MOst And Bottom most screen are not seen in that screen shot image. Help me.

Comment: I'm not sure what's the problem. If you want to capture the whole screen, use the top level window instead of self.view.